# Why codes that does N/2 steps are considered O(N)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Consider a nested loop. The outer loop starts at `i=0` and iterates `N` times, and the inner loop starts at `j=i+1` and iterates up to `j=N`. So the inner loop will roughly do n/2 steps. At the end, however, the runtime is considered **O(N<sup>2</sup>)** Why is the inner loop considered `O(N)` and not `O(N/2)`, since we have other codes that have O(log n) runtimes?

Comment: `O(N) == C*O(N)` where `C` is some *constant* (`C == 1/2` in your case)

Comment: so why this is not the case in the O(log n) cases ?

Comment: O(N) and O(N/2) are exactly the same thing. Time complexity of O(N) means that running time increases linearly with N plus minus some lower order handwaving; if time increases linearly with N it also increases linearly with N/2, and vice-versa.

Comment: It's all about [asymptotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis). Therefore constants can be omitted. Your logn-mentioning makes me think you are misunderstanding something but it's hard to tell. O(log_2 n) is the same as O(log_10 n) for example (because it's just a constant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're *mixing* two different cases (division in the *final formula* - `N**2/C` - where `C` can be *ignored*: `O(N**2/C) == O(N**2)`; and division in the *loop*: `for (int j = N; j >= 1; j /= C)` where `C` leads to *logarithm*):

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
   for (int j = i + 1; j <= N; ++j) 
     SomeOperation(i, j);
```

Let's count the number of `SomeOperation(i, j)` to be performed:

```
 i    j
-------------------
 1    N - 1
 2    N - 2
 3    N - 3
..
 N    0
```

So we have

```
(N - 1) + (N - 2) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0 ==
 N * (N - 1) / 2 == 
 N**2 / 2 - N / 2 ==
 O(N**2 / 2 - N / 2) == O(N**2 / 2) == O(N**2)
```

On the contrary (please, notice `j /= 2` instead of `++j`) which means *far fewer* inner loops

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
   for (int j = N; j >= 1; j /= 2) 
     SomeOperation(i, j);

 i    j
-------------------
 1    log(N)
 2    log(N)
 3    log(N)
..
 N    log(N)
```

And here we have

```
 log(N) + log(N) + ... + log(N) ==
 N * log(N) == 
 O(N * log(N))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) represents the *complexity* of time it takes a segment of code to execute, in proportion to some metric. Usually, the symbols used in braces represent quantities like input size, container size, etc.

In an intuitive sense, `O(N)` refers to *the number of times a code runs in proportion to the symbols included inside the braces*, as opposed to the **exact** number of times it runs. It may run `K = N/2` times in reality, but the point Big-O notation tries to underscore is the fact that, the value of `K` is estimated by how large `N` is, and it is directly proportional to `K`.

To further clarify, notice that for a large enough N, the division by 2 does not really matter, as it is simply a constant factor. The notion that *for a large enough N, constants are negligible* is critical to understand to get a good grasp of various complexity notations, including Big-O.